# How to pass parameters with Object Values through URL

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I created a project that allows converting HTML to PDF. I'm using [phantom-render-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom-render-stream)
 to convert the HTML to PDF. My problem now, I failed to pass an object value to HTML. Below is my code.

**app.js**

```
var username = "AAA";
var pets = [
   {id: 1, name: "cat"},
   {id: 2, name: "dog"},
   {id: 3, name: "sugar glider"}
];
var address = {
    line1: "Street A123",
    town: "Edinburgh",
    country: "Scotland"
};

render('http://localhost:8888/createForm.html?username='+username+'&pets='+pets+'&address='+address
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('customer.pdf'));
```

In `createForm.html`, I used an AngularJS to get and view the value to PDF.

**createForm.html**

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.config(function($locationProvider){
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });

        app.controller('getDataCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
                         var url = decodeURIComponent( $location.url() );
             var value = $location.search();

            $scope.username = value.username;
            $scope.pets = value.pets;
                       $scope.address = value.address;
            })
</script>

<body>
      <div ng-app="onePayForm" ng-controller="getDataCtrl">
           <p>{{username}}</p>
           <p>{{pets[0].name}}</p>
           <p>{{address.line1}}</p>
      </div>
</body>
```

After successfully converting HTML to PDF, I opened the pdf file to see the result. Only username appears in pdf, the rest shows like this `{{pets[0].name}} {{address.line1}}`.

Comment: Post a working jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

```
render('http://localhost:8888/createForm.htmlusername='+username+'&pets='+pets+'&address='+address)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('customer.pdf'));
```

your query params need to be prepared before appending them to the url. What you should do

```
var readyPets = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(pets));
var readyAddress = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(address));
```

then change the code above to :

```
render('http://localhost:8888/createForm.htmlusername='+username+'&pets='+readyPets+'&address='+readyAddress)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('customer.pdf'));
```

in createForm.html parse these param queries:

```
$scope.pets = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(value.pets));
$scope.address = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(value.address));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its worked! Now I know how to use `encodeURIComponent`, `decodeURIComponent`,  `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.